# Issue in lesson 6 of "CREATE AND MANAGE API" course of apigee

Tags: apigee

I am facing issue while submitting the results for lesson 6 of `"CREATE AND MANAGE API"`  course of `APIGEE`. I'm not able to clear it. Though while checking manually the api proxy works as expected
from console I'm getting `200OK` and response payload body as expected and while submitting it for  `WEEK 6 TEST`, I'm getting  message as `not good` which is to say, the response that came back wasn't something we expected. So it's hard to say what went wrong. Here's what we got back with

```
"HTTP status: 200"
```

Comment: Please post your question on the class forum at http://academy.apigee.com/groups/learn-create-and-manage-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible you are hitting a defect in the test tool.  One workaround that was found was to remove the JSON threat protection policy from the proxy side flow.  If that doesn't work for you, email the curl commands to get an access token and to get a joke to help@apigee.com and we'll evaluate it manually.